# T-SQL - Query that operates on multiple tables that have the same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do some investigation and reporting on a SQL Server database and my goal seems simple, yet my brain is just not putting it together.

The goal is to find the total number of records in each table that were created before a certain date. Most (but not all) tables in the database have a column "created", so I just need to find all tables that have that column and run the query on them.

I can easily find all appropriate table names with:

```
select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where column_name = 'created'
```

The next step is to combine that with:

```
select count(*) from ... where created <= date_i_care_about
```

Is there any easy way to do this without looping?

Comment: There is an undocumented stored procedure `sp_MSForEachTable` (http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm) that you can probably adapt to do what you want.

Comment: @Tab Yeah, never mind, misread the question. Still, highly, highly, highly recommend against the undocumented, unsupported, and probably broken sp_MSForEachTable.

Comment: sp_MSForEachTable encapsulates a loop, so technically the answer is still no, you can't do it without looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this a one time job (not used for automation), I think you can copy the result 
of the below query and execute it:

```
DECLARE @date AS DATETIME
SET @date = '2014-01-01'
SELECT 'SELECT ''' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id) + ''' AS [Table], COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM [' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id) + '] WHERE [created] <= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @date, 20) + '''' FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'created'
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Perfect! This is not for automation and I was looking for a quick and dirty solution. The only modification I made was to prefix a "union all" to each statement (deleting the first one of course). This will give me the results all in the same table.